# How to make a correct link to sign in via Facebook using a button from bootstrap-social

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, omniauth-facebook

I'm using Omniauth on my Rails website to make possible sign in with Facebook.

I have the following button:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
```

I followed installation instructions from here:
[Social Sign-In Buttons made in pure CSS based on Bootstrap and Font Awesome](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/)

I need to link the button to sign in using Facebook, making it look similar to:

```
<%= link_to "Login with Facebook", new_user_registration_path %>
```

I tried the following options but no one shows the button correctly:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> <%= link_to "Login via Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
</a>
```

or

```
<%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do %>
<div class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"> 
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution - the following code is correct:

```
<%= link_to user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) do%>
<div class="btn-lg btn-block btn-social btn-facebook"> 
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in with Facebook
</div>
<% end %>
```

It was placed inside `<p></p>` tag, that's why the height was cut